# dynamic chart with Highcharts using json

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts, live-update

I've a question about how to create a dynamic chart using json, I tried and my graph didn't show a result, when I checked out, I've no error with my code. This is my code :

```
    <script>
    var chart; // global

    function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api_heartrate.php', 
            success: function(point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                    shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20

                // add the point
                chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

                // call it again after one second
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'Value',
                    margin: 80
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: []
            }]
        });     
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>`
```

this is my json :
http://health.barrukurniawan.tech/api_heartrate.php
`[{"time":"2018-08-02 09:30:11","nilai_sensor":"78"}]`

I tried following a tutorial from this link :
[Highcharts Dynamic Chart with MySQL Data doesn't reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493295/highcharts-dynamic-chart-with-mysql-data-doesnt-reload)

Thanks for your attention, gladly waiting for an answer :)

Comment: Highcharts is not the same library as Chart.js

Comment: I'm sorry before, i wrote wrong for the title, i mean highchart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple small errors in your approach

1. `eval` is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil), parse it using `JSON.parse` instead.
2. During load, chart is not defined yet, so your callback will not work.
3. Highcharts needs time in milliseconds since 1970.
4. highcharts expects an object `{x: , y: ,...}` you give it `{time: , nilai_sensor: }`.

**Solutions:**

1. `point = JSON.parse(point)`
2. ```
   events: {
     load: function() {
       setInterval(function() {
         requestData(chart)
       }, 1000);
     }
   }
   ```
3. `new Date(point[0].time).getTime()`
4. `{x: new Date(point[0].time).getTime(), y: point[0].nilai_sensor}`

**Here is a working example using your input with static data**(and some added time to keep it moving): https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/md975oLk/23/

Comment: you are my heroo!  yes you are right. I have made a mistake in there. Thanks for the correction